# Linker Error when Archiving a build with RestKit

Tags: ios, restkit

Creating an archive build with XCode 4.5 DP3 I got the following linker error

```
    libRestKit.a(NSManagedObject+ActiveRecord.o), mach-o string pool extends beyond end of file for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Running the debug version of the same code base works fine on the device and in the simulator.  I was only able to create an archive build by opening the project in XCode 4.3.  I didn't change any configurations or settings to get the project to archive.

Does anyone have a clue why this error is happening in XCode 4.5 DP3?

Comment: You realize that you are in violation of the contract you signed with Apple to talk about a pre-release of Xcode in public? You should take this question to the private technical sites on the developer site.

Comment: I just hope someone doesn't waste there time trying to figure out a simple thing like this, the same way I did

Comment: Prereleased software does all kinds of weird things, that is why it is not released yet. Try the Apple forums instead to discuss issues in connection with their beta software!

Comment: This bug happens in other libraries also. You must discuss it in the apple developer forums.